# How can I extract out a serving unit and serving size array? Regex formula?

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

I want to extract the numbers and words from a string into a serving_unit array and a serving_size array.

**For example:**

```
"56 g (0.5 cup)" would create serving_size_array=[56 , 0.5] & serving_unit_array=["g", "cup"]
```

***or***

```
"1 ARTICHOKE, EDIBLE (120 g)" would create serving_size_array=[1, 120] & serving_unit_array=["ARTICHOKE, EDIBLE", "g"]
```

**some easy sample values:**

```
"47 g (0.25 cup)"
"47 g (0.25 cup)"
"56 g (0.5 cup)"
"40 g (0.25 cup)"
```

**some not-so-easy sample values:**

```
"2 SLICES (57 g)"
"3.0g"
"serving"
"1 ARTICHOKE, EDIBLE (120 g)"
"1/4 pizza (133 g)"
"1 pizza 52 g"
"42 g (0.5 DRY NOODLE BLOCK AND 1 TSP SEASONING MIX | ABOUT)"
"4 COOKIES, PER CONTAINER ABOUT (15 g)"
"15 ASSORTED NUTS | APPROX. (30 g)"
"Per 1 piece (1.9 g)"
"1 piece (1.9 g) (1.9 g)"
```

I am using javascript for this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm < 1 year into my Full Stack Development journey. In the tech test of my first job there were 3 (THREE!!) Regex questions.

Assuming all items you need to get access too come following serving_unit_array, I can recommend some resources to learn/ play with Regex:

1. https://regexone.com/
2. https://regex101.com/
3. https://regexr.com/

You can do it!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are easy if you know they're always going to be in the same format, but the units are much harder because the location or format isn't fixed.

For the numbers you could use the following:

```
(?:\d+\/\d+)|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

with:

- The first group `(?:\d+\/\d+)` matches fractions such as 1/4
- The second group `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches integers or decimals

[Regex 101 link](https://regex101.com/r/PA9T72/1) to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is really very simple:

**For number:**
https://regex101.com/r/DsAlRS/1

**For string:**
https://regex101.com/r/HbgA0T/1

Good luck !

Comment: These seem to only return one number or string. Not an array of all instances of each. Is there a way to grab all instances of numbers, for example, and place them in a corresponding array?

Comment: This is on another level of question, now that you have the corresponding regexs, it's up to you to create a function that does what you want, and believe it it's not complicated ... If you can't, come back to me :)